# Create API using Amazon lambda function and API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am implementing an API using Amazon lambda function and API Gateway this lambda function will, in turn, call another 3rd party API and will transform that data into a specific format and will return it.

The 3rd part API that I am using to fetch records has pagination and throttling enabled but the API I am building using lambda and API Gateway I don't want to implement pagination in it rather I want this API to get all the pages one by one transform them in the specific format and return at once. The Client of this API should not have to call it with different pagination parameters.

Now as Lambda function has a maximum of 15-minute limit and the 3rd part API also has a max request per minute limit what is the best way to implement this.

This is how I am doing it right now, in my lambda function I push a specific number of requests in promises and when the max number is reached I stop pushing more and execute the pending promises and set a timeout function for one minute meanwhile the pending promises executes and I generate the response from them but don't send it back as there are pending requests to be made. When the timeout completes I again push a specific amount of requests in promises and repeat the process.

Once all the pages are completed I return the data.

Now the problem is this may exceed more than 15 minutes and the lambda function would terminate.

Is there a better approach for this, even by using some other amazon services.

Comment: Are the data the same for all API clients ?  Or depending on client's identity ?  Also, how frequently data from 3rd party API are changing ?  Depending on these answer I would probably suggest to cache the data on your API side and build the data set asynchronously.  Having an API returning result after several minutes (possibly 15 minutes) is not a good customer experience and is not something I would recommend.  There is a reason why the 3rd party API implemented pagination.

Comment: Actually, this API that I am building with lambda is not to be exposed to the end uses, it will be used by another product to fetch records via cron jobs. The user will decide how frequent his data should be fetched like daily on a specific time, in this case, we will only fetch data for the current day, or the user can select once a week, in this case, we will fetch data for one week at once. I am open with the concept of pagination in my API but only as a last resort, like if lambda function's 15 min limit is exceeded than I would send next page info.

Comment: Each user will have their own unique data on that 3rd party API, its change frequency is not predictable so we need to fetch new data each time.

Comment: this sounds more like a batch job than an API.  What about a REST API call to trigger the job and an asynchronous notification when the job is finished ?  Asynchronous notifications can be implemented with SQS, API Gateway + WebSocket or (worst case) polling.

Comment: that makes sense as I just found out that APIGateway has a 30 seconds max timeout limit so what I am trying to accomplish can't be done in traditional API way.